# CSS Design of Flex Cards like iOS 11 App Store Cards

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to find a way to recreate the iOS 11 App Store card effect for the Today tab, where each post is a card that, when tapped, expands to full screen.

Searching for this hasn't helped as all I get are results *about* the App Store and iOS 11.

What I'm starting with are a grid of flex cards (loosely based on Bootstrap 4 cards). I want to be able to tap one card and expand that card to full-screen viewing, and tapping an (x) restores the card to its original position.

I have tried changing the card to `position:fixed` with `top:0` and `left:0` and some other possibilities explored in this SO post: [How do you expand a FlexBox item to full screen without moving the other Flex items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725208/how-do-you-expand-a-flexbox-item-to-full-screen-without-moving-the-other-flex-it)
However, I have the same issues with the other flex cards jumping around, or the clicked card jumping from its original location to the top of the viewport.

Here's a link to a screen recording in case you aren't sure what I mean or don't have an iOS 11 device:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/arozweveil25cct/iOS%2011%20App%20Store%20Card.mp4?dl=0

What I'm asking for is some advice to get started or a link to a post that explores something similar to this. I just feel at a total loss on how to move forward. Thanks!

### Cards HTML

```
<div class="row cards">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-text">
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      <p>Card content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-text">
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      <p>Card content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-text">
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      <p>Card content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Cards SCSS

```
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;

  .card {
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    margin-bottom: $space/2;

    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
      flex: 0 1 45%;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: $space/2 2.5%;
    }
    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
      flex: 0 1 30%;
      margin: $space/2 1.666%
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide a minimal working code sample you need help with.

Comment: First off, the `@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {` rule's `flex-direction: column;` won't work as it should be set on the flex container, not flex item, second, with `transform: translate` you can zoom your items and the other won't jump around

Comment: @LGSon
The cards themselves are flex items as they contain additional elements. I use the default `flex-direction: row` for `.cards`.

Also, `transform: translate` seems to be only relative to the element, and so viewport-relative values aren't a possibility. The values given for translation move the element *by* that amount, not *to* that position.

Comment: For that you could add an extra wrapper between the `card` and content, and move/size that instead of the flex item

Comment: That solves the problem described in the originally linked SO question, where adjacent flex items would jump around when moving a sibling item. I still don't know how to animate that interior element to the equivalent of `top:0 left:0`